# C# keydown event storing in char variables

Tags: c#

I'm wondering how I could just store the pressed key in a char variable (C#).
Could anyone help me?

with kind regards,
dutchjelly

(is it possible to do this?)

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char c = e.KeyChar;
        if(c = 'A')
        {
            do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean Char(13)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    char c = Convert.ToChar(e.KeyCode);
    if (c == 69)
    {
        do something
    }
}
```

where 69 represents an [ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (in this case `E`, you can search for other on google).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Keys k = e.KeyCode; //This is your key code
}
```

The same way you could store the pressed keys to a List or some structure of your need:

```
List<Keys> keys = new List<Keys>();
keys.Add(k);
```

EDIT:

In the case you just want to get the char value of what the user has pressed you can do this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    char c = e.KeyChar;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to have the key I press to show as an output in a textbox. Is there any way I could do that using a char variable to store the pressed key?

Comment: when I try this it gives an error that states: cannot convert 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys' to 'char'